# NDVI Web services over Victoria australia

Tags: web-service, well-known-text, ndvi, australia, soap

Does anyone know of any web services that are available where you can pass...say a WKT polygon or point and return the mean NDVI or NDVI from that point from an array of the most recent NDVI runs?

Comment: I'm not aware of any NDVI web services, but BOM NDVI images are available for download. http://www.bom.gov.au/jsp/awap/ndvi/index.jsp?colour=colour&time=latest&step=0&map=ndviave&period=month&area=nat

Comment: Thanks, I have seen those in the past. I see the google earth engine api run a beta service that gets part of the way(UI dashboard). Would be great to know if the google earth engine does have this facility if anyone is in the know?

Comment: Ok, I found some services which appear to have NDVI for Australia. http://134.178.63.198/thredds/catalog/avhrr_ndvi_5km_monthly/2008/catalog.html?dataset=bureau_tern_avhrr_ndvi_5km_monthly/2008/C-bawap.D1-20080701.D2-20080731.I-P1M.V-ndvi-5km-1month.P-raw.DC-20090810T063523.DM-20120601T074444.nc

Looks like you need to register for access.  I was able to load the WMS into ArcGIS, however.  Also doesn't look to up to date.

Comment: More recent data at http://opendap.bom.gov.au:8080/thredds/catalogs/bmrc-tern-catalog.html but note the access restrictions.

Comment: The [opendata.se] Stack Exchange may be a more suitable site for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this myself using python, sentinel hub and aws amazon sentinel 2 s3 store. This script looks at the sent2List array and loops through each sentinel array item to download from aws as band 4 & * tiles. first it check to see if it exists from the metadata and if the cloud cover meets the . It processes the images rasterio using the "cloudypixelPercentage" criteria . 
Its very rough but works...from my end anyway. I have used the tile/bands that intersect our Goulburn Murray Irrigation District in Victoria Australia. Hope it helps someone.

```
 import sentinelhub
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import urllib
import gdal
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
import os
import json
import urllib2
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform, reproject

sent2TileList = ['54/H/XF','54/H/XG','55/H/BA','55/H/CV','55/H/BB','55/H/DA','54/H/YE','54/H/YF','54/H/YG','55/H/BV','55/H/CA','55/H/DV'] #list of GMID intersecting Tiles



def reproject(file2, proj):
    input_raster = gdal.Open(file2)
    gdal.Warp(proj,input_raster,dstSRS='EPSG:3111')

def downloadSent(a, b):
    for e in sent2TileList:
        patha='../NDVI/Unprocessed/Sent_B4_'+e.replace("/","_")+'_'+b+'.jp2'
        print patha
        pathb='../NDVI/Unprocessed/Sent_B8_'+e.replace("/","_")+'_'+b+'.jp2'
        urlopnPath ='http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/'+e+'/'+a+'/0/tileInfo.json'
        print urlopnPath
        tilejson=urllib2.urlopen(urlopnPath)
        print tilejson
        jdata= json.load(tilejson)
        if os.path.isfile('../NDVI/Unprocessed/Sent_B4_'+e+'_'+b+'.jp2')==True:
            print "Sentinal 2 file exists"
            processNDVI(patha, pathb,b,e)
        elif jdata["cloudyPixelPercentage"] > 60:
            print "Cloud cover is greater than 15%"
            print jdata["cloudyPixelPercentage"]

        else:
            print "downloading "+e+" band 4 and 8 from AWS"
            print '..//NDVI//Unprocessed//Sent_B4_'+e+'_'+b+'.jp2'
            sentinelhub.download_data(('http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/'+e+'/'+a+'/0/B04.jp2', '..//NDVI//Unprocessed//Sent_B4_'+e.replace("/","_")+'_'+b.replace("/","_")+'.jp2'))
            sentinelhub.download_data(('http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/'+e+'/'+a+'/0/B08.jp2', '..//NDVI//Unprocessed//Sent_B8_'+e.replace("/","_")+'_'+b.replace("/","_")+'.jp2'))

            processNDVI(patha, pathb, b, e)


def processNDVI(b4, b8, b, e):
    if os.path.isfile('../NDVI/Unprocessed/Sent_NDVI_'+e.replace("/","_")+'_'+b.replace("/","_")+'.tif')==True:
        print "NDVI file exists"
    else:
        outfile = r'../NDVI/Unprocessed/Sent_NDVI_'+e.replace("/","_")+'_'+b.replace("/","_")+'.tif'
        print "Processing NDVI"
        with rio.Env(GDAL_SKIP='JP2ECW'):
            with rio.open(b4) as red:
                RED = red.read()
        with rio.open(b8) as nir:
            NIR = nir.read()
        #compute the ndvi
        RED=RED.astype('float')
        NIR-NIR.astype('float')
        ndvi = (NIR-RED)/(NIR+RED)
        ##ndvi = ndvi.astype(rio.float32)
        print "ndvi=",ndvi
        print(ndvi.min(), ndvi.max()) ##The problem is alredy here
        profile = red.meta
        print profile
        profile.update(driver='GTiff')
        profile.update(dtype=rio.float32)
        #print "ndvi after floatupdate=",ndvi.astype(rio.float32)
        with rio.open(outfile, 'w', **profile) as dst:
            dst.write(ndvi)
        print "NDVI Sentinel 2 complete"
        print profile

        projTiff ='../NDVI/Sent_NDVI_'+e.replace("/","_")+'_'+b.replace("/","_")+'.tif'
        reproject(outfile, projTiff)
        dst.closed

pathStatus = False
count = 0

while (pathStatus == False):
    pathYear1 = datetime.now()
    pathYear= pathYear1-timedelta(days=count)
    y1=pathYear.year
    m1=pathYear.month
    d1=pathYear.day
    dateStructure=str(y1)+"/"+str(m1)+"/"+str(d1)
    filedateStructure =str(y1)+""+str(m1)+""+str(d1)
    URLPath="http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/55/H/CV/"+dateStructure+"/0/tileInfo.json"

    if urllib.urlopen(URLPath).getcode() == 404:
        count += 1
        pathStatus=False

    elif urllib.urlopen(URLPath).getcode() == 200:
         count += 1
         pathStatus=True
         downloadSent(dateStructure, filedateStructure)
    else:
        downloadSent(dateStructure, filedateStructure)
        pathStatus= True
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not investigated these in any detail but the Atlas of Living Australia seems to have an [NDVI Mean](http://spatial.ala.org.au/layers/more/ndvi_mean) layer available:

> Normalised difference vegetation index (NDVI*100)